# Traversing table and returning clicked element's placement

Tags: javascript

I have an `onclick` function attached to each `<td>` element. The function needs to know the placement in the table (row and column).

I found an attribute called `rowIndex` for `<tr>`s, but that would involve getting the parent element and still doesn't help with column number.

Here is my function so far (it's within a loop, so it's attaching to every td)

```
td.onclick = function(event) {
  event = (event) ? event : window.event;
  console.log('rowIndex, colIndex');
}
```

I could figure this out with jQuery, but I'm trying to do without.

Comment: What about cells that span multiple columns or rows? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thoughts were:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var cellsPerRow = cells.length/rows.length;
var i = 0;
for (r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
    for (c=0;c<cellsPerRow;c++){
        cells[i].setAttribute('data-col',c + 1);
        cells[i].setAttribute('data-row',r + 1);
        cells[i].onclick = function(){
            var row = this.getAttribute('data-row');
            var col = this.getAttribute('data-col');
            alert('Row: ' + row + '; col: ' + col);
        };
    i++;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6STK5/).

This was then refined to:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
    cells[i].onclick = function(){
        var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;
        var col = this.cellIndex + 1;
        alert('Row: ' + row + '; col: ' + col);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6STK5/1/).

Answer (score 2):

```
element.cellIndex
```

will give you the column zero-indexed position.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bFCNG/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible in your situation to echo out the row and column into the td element's id in the server-side script? Such as **...id="' . $row . '_' . $col . '"...**

Then it's just a case of parsing the values out from **this.id**.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/Lu8Yw/

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var td = tds[i];
    td.onclick = function(event) {
        event = (event) ? event : window.event;
        console.log('rowIndex: ' + this.parentNode.rowIndex + ', colIndex: ' + this.cellIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, creating click events for each td is not efficient. Recommend using event delegation. You can google it for the benefits of using Event delegation.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/

Basically, the more cells you have in the table, the more memory will be consumed. Instead of creating multiple cells, create one single event to delegate.

```
var table = document.getElementById('test-table');

table.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.target,
        parent;

    if (target.tagName === 'TD') {
        parent = target.parentNode;
        console.log('rowIndex', parent.getAttribute('rowindex'), 'colIndex', target.getAttribute('colindex'));
    }
}
```

Here is the example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWGzB/1/